# form with javascript code in wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, forms

I want to create same form in wordpress with javascript code as mentioned. Please guide me how to create a similar form and where to post this javascript code. This code is perfectly working when we save this code in html document. But I am unaware where to save this code in wordpress.
Many Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function DisplayPrice(price){
        var val1 = 0;
        for( i = 0; i < document.form1.price.length; i++ ){
            if( document.form1.price[i].checked == true ){
                val1 = document.form1.price[i].value;
            }
        }

        var val2 = 0;
        for( i = 0; i < document.form2.price2.length; i++ ){
            if( document.form2.price2[i].checked == true ){
                val2 = document.form2.price2[i].value;
            }
        }

        var sum=parseInt(val1) + parseInt(val2);
        document.getElementById('totalSum').value=sum;
    }
    </script>
 </head>
 <body>
   Choose a number:<br>
   <form name="form1" id="form1" runat="server">
    <br>
    <input id="rdo_1" type="radio" value="159" name="price"                              onclick="DisplayPrice(this.value);">159
    <br>
    <input id="rdo_2" type="radio" value="259" name="price" onclick="DisplayPrice(this.value);">259
    <br>
       </form>

    Choose another number:<br>
     <form name="form2" id="form2" runat="server">
    <br>
    <input id="rdo_1" type="radio" value="345" name="price2" onclick="DisplayPrice(this.value);">345
    <br>
    <input id="rdo_2" type="radio" value="87" name="price2" onclick="DisplayPrice(this.value);">87
    <br>
   </form>
   <input type="text" name="totalSum" id="totalSum" value="" size="2" readonly="readonly">


    </body>
```

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ will be more relevant for this question

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to add this code to wordpress

1 . In your theme folder -> your activated theme -> index.php

2 . In your plugin folder -> create new plugin folder with any name -> add this code by creating index.php file in plugin

add following lines to top of index.php

/*
Plugin Name: name of plugin

Version: 1.0

Plugin URI:

Description:

Author:

Author URL :

activate plugin with name you have given.

test for form.